# When exchange Activity black screen

Tags: android, layout

I have a problem when I call an activity.
The screen goes black, and when it is done properly preload the layout then shows the activity.

The problem is that the layout needs to load is really heavy.

**How can I manage this thing is not very good?**

This is the my code, I tried to do various tests:

1 Syncronize
2 AsinkTask

```
if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        /*
         * ----------------- TAB DATA -----------------
         */
        try {

            System.gc();
            //initialize the class that needs to load the Activity
            myLayout = new TableMainLayout(this);
            //I tried to give some time to load, but that's not good!
            synchronized (this) {
                wait(5000);
            }

            setContentView(myLayout);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("link", "Errore actionBarTabs update  Series: " + e);
        }
    }
```

**But to no avail. Can you tell me any solution? Or advice?**

EDIT : 
**Update Code:** 
[TableMainLayout.java](https://piratenpad.de/ep/pad/view/ro.Dx4kuD5kF7y/latest)

**my problem is that I can not figure out exactly when the layout is ready. I tried to put it in an async but nothing, I tried to syncronize but nothing. It would be enough just a simple example of how to figure out when the layout is loaded and ready to be displayed. Then I'll customize it to my code.**

Comment: Using `System.gc();` is not good, same goes for ` wait(5000)`. Have you tried to add some animation when replacing Activity?

Comment: instead using wait simply show loading dialog until layout loaded.

Comment: @BlazeTama Using GC because of the time goes in OutOfMemory. Why should I use an animation? would not be all heavier?

Comment: @HareshChhelana This is exactly what I'd do. Can you give me an example or give me advice on the implementation? if you need other pieces of code you ask.

Comment: @uynva how about **Haresh's** suggestion?

Comment: @uynva i m with Haresh's  loading dialog

Comment: I was thinking in the onCreate () I create a ProgressDialog. But where can I end the ProgressDialog?

Comment: @uynva,can you please post some code then we get idea how to implement loader.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I edited the code where I build the layout. As you can see it is very heavy load. And in some devices causes OutOfMemory.

Comment: @uynva,try to implement custom interface and give call back to activity when layout ready with data.

Comment: @HareshChhelana OK. my problem is that I can not figure out exactly when the layout is ready. I tried to put it in an async but nothing, I tried to syncronize but nothing. It would be enough just a simple example of how to figure out when the layout is loaded and ready to be displayed. Then I'll customize it to my code.